# Should I normalize or add FK to each table

Tags: sql, database, join, foreign-keys, normalization

I have been having my doubts about the database design used in a project I am working on. I have three tables: `Event`, `ProductEvents` and `Product`. `ProductEvents` is a linking table between `Event` and `Product`. Both `Event` and `Product` have the same foreign key.

For deleting records in the `ProductEvents` table, I have no foreign key to `Estate`, and thus need to join before deleting. Now I wonder what the best solution is: either add the foreign key or join with the `Event` or `Product` table for each query that needs to be done.

Taking the normalisation rules into account, I should only consider the join option. However, for this problem there is also a background story. We have other tables, e.g. `House` and `Interior` where `Interior` has a FK to `House`. `House` has a discriminator to `Estate` and contains a rough 10 million records. `Interior` contains a couple 100 millions records. Only recently we were forced to add the discriminator to the `Interior` table as well because the joins were getting too heavy, and slow, even when we were making sure the result set stayed as small as possible.

What is the best/common practice for this problem? Is it better to have a common discriminator in each table, or stick to the joins?

[image: ERD scetch]

Comment: I feel kind of stupid, but I must admit I don't know what a discriminator is. What does "Both Event and product have the same discriminator" mean? Can you show table structures to illustrate what you are talking about?

Comment: No need to feel stupid. Perhaps I am using the wrong keyword. What I meant was foreign key. Updated description accordingly and added ERD sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design your database based on natural keys or technical IDs. With the latter you get (primary key in bold):

- Estate (**estate_id**, estate_no, name ...)
- Product (**product_id**, product_no, estate_id, name, ...)
- Event (**event_id**, event_code, estate_id, name, ...)
- ProductEvents (**productevents_id**, product_id, event_id, ...)

Here is the same with natural keys:

- Estate (**estate_no**, name ...)
- Product (**estate_no, product_no**, name, ...)
- Event (**estate_no, event_code**, name, ...)
- ProductEvents (**estate_no, product_no, event_code**, ...)

So, yes, when working with technical IDs you need a join when you want to access ProductEvents for a specific Estate. This shows both strengths and weaknesses of the technical ID design:

1. pro: The natural key is in only one place. If you decide to use estate number 'AX123' instead of 'AE123' then change it in one place and you are done.
2. pro: Changes to the data structure are easy. If an event doesn't belong to an estate any longer, but to an estate group now, this is a minor change compared to changes needed in a natural key based database.
3. con: Access to data often involves many tables to get from the given natural keys to the technical IDs needed.
4. con: Data consistency cannot be guaranteed by the dbms.

As to the last point: Although the database is normalized (this is the case in both models by the way), it is possible with the ID design to have a ProductEvents referencing two different estates (one via Event, the other via Product). The DBMS can not ensure that only products and events for the same estate can be combined in ProductEvents. With natural keys it can, because ProductEvents has foreign keys to Event(estate_no, event_code) and Product(estate_no, product_no) and there is just the one estate_no in ProductEvents.

Having worked with both, I prefer the natural key design for large databases. However, one can even mix both. And yes, you can even add the estate_id to ProductEvents. It is no longer the pure ID design you had, but helps access data faster and you can add foreign keys to Event(event_id, estate_id) and Product(product_id, estate_id) to enhance data consistency checks. I wouldn't even consider this non-normalized (but I may be wrong about this).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your insight on this, and providing me with two approaches, as well as a pro-con breakdown!